# app.yaml problem python standard app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use the app.yaml in Python 3.8 for Google app engine standard.

My app.yaml looks like this;

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

I can then access all the files in the directory named "static".

If I then change app.yaml to;

```
runtime: python38
handlers:
- url: /staticX
  static_dir: staticX
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

If I then try to access any files in "staticX" I get a 404 error.
However I can still access the files in "static". Even a hard refresh gets a 200.

Changing app.yaml has no effect.

Comment: Try a different browser and see if the same result happens. Do you have files in `staticX`?

Comment: Tried a different browser, same problem. the 200 and 404 codes are logged. This problem is on a local windows machine. If I edit the main.py file, I get "Detected change ... reloading" , no such message appears when I edit app.yaml

Comment: what do you mean by "changing app.yaml"? are you redeploying the app successfully?

Comment: All this is on the development server.
If I deploy (to appspot)  the second app.yaml (staticX), I can access both directories static and staticX. This is weird

Comment: What's your scaling type? Do you use traffic splitting? Do you have cache management/CDN?

Comment: I have take the quickstart for python 3 and edited it as above, nothing else.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a matter of caching. According to google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-handled#static_cache_expiration) static handlers in Google App Engine is cached and, if you do not set value `default_expiration`, it will be still available in default 10 minutes.

I have done the same test on my side and indeed after redeployment `static_dir` are still available for around 10m. I noticed that if I start to deploy and redeploy all over again, 10-20 times, sometimes the time seems to be longer than 10m. However, finally, when I check after a few hours, all changes have been available.

Comment: I added: default_expiration: "0d 1m"
Still having the exact same problems, after many hours.
Time for a fresh install of Windows 10 on the laptop and see if this problem persists.
Thanks for trying

Comment: There is no connection between the issue and your local machine. The app is deployed into the cloud and you should be able to do it from any machine. I am not able to replicate this issue, but if you are sure that the issue still persist please try to raise issue tracker like here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/community#file_feature_requests_and_defects, it may be something related with your account only